# Does any software exist to tweak my Ubuntu system to remove the cruft?

Tags: ubuntu, performance

Does any software exist to tweak my Ubuntu system to remove the cruft?

I'm looking for something that's disable services, delete configuration directories for software that's no longer installed, etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/).

Description of Ubuntu Tweak features on its website:

> At present, It is only designed for
>   Ubuntu GNOME Desktop, and often
>   follows the newest Ubuntu
>   distribution.

```
* View of Basic System Information(Distribution, Kernel, CPU, Memory, etc.)
* GNOME Session Control
* Auto Start Program Control
* Qucik install common usded applications
* A lot of third-party sources to keep application up-to-date
* Clean unneeded packages or cache to free the disk space
* Show/Hide and Change Splash screen
* Show/Hide desktop icons or Mounted Volumes
* Show/Hide/Rename Computer, Home, Trash icon or Network icon
* Tweak Metacity Window Manager’s Style and Behavior
* Compiz Fusion settings, Screen Edge Settings, Window Effects Settings, Menu Effect Settings
* Set the Shortcuts to let qucikly access your favourite applications
* GNOME Panel Settings
* Nautilus Settings
* Advanced Power Management Settings
* System Security Settings
```

You should also look into the [deborphan](http://freshmeat.net/projects/deborphan/) and [debfoster](http://directory.fsf.org/project/debfoster/) packages that help you rid yourself of packages that are no longer needed.

Edit: [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/19603/how-do-i-remove-kde-from-ubuntu-if-i-decide-not-to-stick-with-it/19696#19696) to my response to a similar question, one that has examples of how debfoster and deborphan are used in practice.