# How to remove the Ubuntu Gnome desktop after making the switch to KDE?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, kde, kubuntu

This is the opposite of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/19603/how-do-i-remove-kde-from-ubuntu-if-i-decide-not-to-stick-with-it).  Basically I've been using Ubuntu for a while but decided to give KDE a shot so I went through the process of getting the latest KDE installed. I'm very impressed with KDE and the Kwin window manager seems like a better WM than Compiz which is what I was using for Gnome (sure that's an oppinion).

This was an Ubuntu Jaunty install. So how do I go about removing the Gnome desktop? Is there an automated way similar to what my [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/19603/how-do-i-remove-kde-from-ubuntu-if-i-decide-not-to-stick-with-it) covered?

UPDATE: Should there be any packages I should NOT remove in the process?

Comment: The answer is essentially the same as your previous question. You just need to find the equivalent meta-package. It's probably `gnome` or `gnome-desktop-environment`.

Comment: Even if that is the case, I think it is well worth having both of the two as stand-alone questions on Super User.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `purge` command is a good start. In addition, you probably want to remove all the dependent libraries that were installed only to get Gnome. You can do that via `autoremove` in `apt-get` or, if you use `aptitude`, it should happen automatically.

Note that the `purge` command has an oddity: it purges items you remove explicitly, but only *removes* any automatically removed dependent packages. (That is, if you enter `aptitude purge foo-bar` and `fizzbuzz` gets automatically removed at the same time, `foo-bar` is purged but `fizzbuzz` is only removed.) So a good way to recursively purge is this:

`aptitude purge foo-bar && aptitude purge ~c`

The [`~c` search](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html#searchConfigFiles) in `aptitude` finds any packages that were removed but not purged in the first removal.

One final note, if you haven't been using `aptitude`, always check its output the first time you try to run it. Don't simply say "Yes" to whatever it wants to do. Depending on what package manager you've been using, you may find that `aptitude` thinks some things should be autoremoved, but you prefer to keep them.

Comment: I take it the Ubuntu Software Centre doesn't purge?

Comment: @BloodyIron To be honest, I'm not sure. I don't think the Ubuntu Software Centre existed the last time I used Ubuntu. I'm more comfortable with the command-line tools (and Debian), but there may be a GUI or Ubuntu-specific way to do it as well.

Comment: well, I'm a fan of the CLI too, but I like the idea of a GUI front end not lacking in features (such as purge). Having such shortcomings in a GUI app/frontend just limits a user who doesn't want to use CLI, why not put it in? I'm curious as I don't know either.

Answer (score 20):

Ubuntu has a built-in tool for changing the type of system you are running.

```
$ sudo tasksel
```

This tool lets you check the box next to the type of system you want (Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu, Ubuntu Server) and then confirm to have the tool re-configure your system, removing and adding packages as needed.

Comment: Debian has this too, just for the record.

Answer (score 8):

I think the simplest way to do this is to remove *ubuntu-desktop* and install *kubuntu-desktop*.

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get --purge remove ubuntu-desktop
```

You can also just uninstall *gnome-desktop-environment* instead of *ubuntu-desktop*.

Comment: Is there *any* difference between uninstalling gnome-desktop-environment and ubuntu-desktop?

Comment: @Jonik: I use Debian not Ubuntu, so I can't test it. But in general, you can find out by simply entering `aptitude -s purge thing1` and then `aptitude -s purge thing2`. The `-s` flag is for *simulate*, and it allows you to check things safely (and as a regular user - no need to become root first or use `sudo`).

Comment: @Jonik: Afaik, ubuntu-desktop includes gnome and some gnome apps. http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/whichbuntu. You can also check the package dependencies using `apt-cache showpkg package_name`.

Comment: That won't work. In the standard Ubuntu install, *everything* is marked as manually installed, so when you `sudo aptitude purge ubuntu-desktop`, only the meta-package is removed; all of GNOME remains installed.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you cant totally remove Gnome because, many common programs on Ubuntu (read Firefox) use Gnome Libraries.

Comment: If he likes KDE that much, he can always switch to Konquerer and remove Firefox entirely, no?

Comment: @Telemachus: tried Konquerer... not for me. :) but I've actually been using Chromium for my default browser lately, the nightly builds are very nice. Have to use Firefox for Quake Live though.

Comment: Of course, Chromium *also* uses GTK...

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not 100% but I'm fairly sure the equivalent meta package is gnome-desktop

That's right... I removed gnome by this:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-*
```