# How can I re-arrange the order of the boot menu?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, kubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [Aesthetically editing grub.cfg](https://superuser.com/questions/111302/aesthetically-editing-grub-cfg)
>   [Make grub keep its default boot under kernel updates](https://superuser.com/questions/102692/make-grub-keep-its-default-boot-under-kernel-updates)

I have installed Ubuntu and Kubuntu on my same machine.

How can I rearrange the order of the boot menu and set the 'default' option if I don't click anything?  Is the boot menu called GRUB or something like that?

I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 and Kubuntu 10.04 on different partition (same hard drive). and Windows 7 on a different hard drive.

The boot menu order now is:

1. Kubuntu
2. memtest
3. Windows 7
4. Ubuntu 10.04 kernel 2.6.32.22

I want to change to:

1. Ubuntu 10.04 kernel 2.6.32.22
2. Windows 7
3. Kubuntu
4. memtest

These are the files in my ubuntu /etc/grub.d:

```
/etc/grub.d$        ls
00_header*        10_linux*       30_os-prober*  README
05_debian_theme*  20_memtest86+*  40_custom*
```

Comment: the boot menu is GRUB, the GRand Unified Bootloader.  have you installed Ubuntu and Kubuntu to the same partition, or to different partitions?  normally they get installed to the same partition, and you just login to a Ubuntu/Gnome session or a Kubuntu session.  (see http://superuser.com/questions/30112/kubuntu-to-ubuntu for details of how you *should* switch from one to the other, if you've already installed one.)

Comment: your question is probably answered in http://superuser.com/questions/102692/make-grub-keep-its-default-boot-under-kernel-updates or in http://superuser.com/questions/111302/aesthetically-editing-grub-cfg or in http://superuser.com/questions/137875/can-grub-be-configured-to-remember-the-last-os-you-booted-into -- please read them first, and edit your question to note what you don't understand, so answers here can specify.  without further information this will likely be closed as a duplicate of one of those or another question.