# How can I complete remove gnome and all of its subprograms?

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, purge, apt

I have Kubuntu 12.04.

And I had installed gnome with `sudo apt-get install gnome`.

How can I complete remove this?

Looks like just put a `sudo apt-get purge gnome` will not solve the case. Because will remove just all `gnome*` packages and subprograms like `brasero` or `seahorse` would be still alive.

How can I complete remove gnome and all of its subprograms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
$ sudo apt-get remove gnome
```

or

```
$ sudo apt-get remove gnome*
```

you can always use the manual for more information

`$ man apt-get`

Comment: `sudo sudo` works, very strange. I think remove ends this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove gnome packages by:

```
apt-get remove gnome-session gnome gnome-shell
```

Then apt-get can remove dependency that have been automatically installed and are not needed anymore with the autoremove command:

```
apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered here: [How to remove the Ubuntu Gnome desktop after making the switch to KDE?](https://superuser.com/questions/28781/how-to-remove-the-ubuntu-gnome-desktop-after-making-the-switch-to-kde)

Maybe it should be moved to http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

First, check what is going to be removed

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep .gnome.
```

If you are ok with it, run this command

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge gnome*
```

Command explanation

```
# dpkg -l       lists all installed packages
# grep .gnome.   filters, so that only packages with keyword gnome within their names, listed
# purge         removes mentioned package
# autoremove    tries to remove dependency packages
```