# How can I display the list of all packages installed on my Debian system?

Tags: linux, debian, aptitude

How can I get the list of all packages installed on my Debian system (I know this one is easy)? And also a list of all packages marked as manual? I am thinking about system upgrade, but I can't remember all these things I installed over the years :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Getting the list of installed packages is simple:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep "[[:space:]]install$" >  installed_pkgs
```

You can later reinstall the packages in the list using this command:

```
dpkg --set-selections < installed_pkgs
sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade
```

If you've used **aptitude** exclusively to manually install packages, it is very easy to get a nice list of manually installed packages. Otherwise, this list will include both packages you installed, and their dependencies.

In either case, read through this article and comments for a coherent solution to generating the list of manually installed packages: [**Cleaning up a Debian GNU/Linux system**](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/462).

You might find [**deborphan** and **debfoster**](https://superuser.com/questions/19603/how-do-i-remove-kde-from-ubuntu-if-i-decide-not-to-stick-with-it/19696#19696) of help in maintaining this list in future.

Comment: deborphan among other things returns diff and other essential packages though - so I wouldn't really recommend using it.

Answer (score 3):

```
dpkg -l
```

to list all installed packages.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it. As root, run the following:

`dpkg --get-selections | sed 's/\t.*//' > packages-list.txt`

This will produce a nice, clean list of installed packages, perfect for using with apt-get install.

Or a crude way to get a list of the packages you have manually installed with aptitude you can grep the logs with something like

`zcat /var/log/aptitude.* | grep INSTALL] && cat /var/log/aptitude| grep INSTALL]`

(But beware, installs with aot-get or dpkg will not get recorded here, plus logrotate might have archived part of the log, which this method will not pick up!)

Answer (score 1):

**dpkg -l** will list installed packages, as suggested.

I suggest to use **upgrade-system** for package upgrade, as it (wrapping  *deborphan*) will purge away old un-needed packages too. This takes your system reasonably both **up-to-date** and **clean**.