# How to get all the application installed in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find all user-installed packages](https://superuser.com/questions/48374/find-all-user-installed-packages)

I am creating an software that get need to display all the installed application in ubuntu .Where all the installed application will be in linux and how can i get the Name,icon of the installed application

Answer (score 0):

This will show you all installed packages:  dpkg -l . In X you could use synaptic package manager.

Comment: Note that this only displays the applications installed through the package manager.  It does not show applications that are installed from source etc.